# RethinkDB serialize/marshall ReQL

Tags: rethinkdb

Is it possible to create a ReQL query in the front-end then serialize it to JSON, post it to the server where it is unmarshalled and executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write ReQL queries in the front-end, you can use [`rehtinkdb-websocket-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rethinkdb-websocket-client) along with [`rethinkdb-websocket-server`](https://github.com/mikemintz/rethinkdb-websocket-server) to do this.

Keep in mind that this will mean that anyone will be able to access your server from the browser, which is a huge security risk.

Comment: Yes that would be a great concern. Thats why marshalling queries would sound to me like the most feasible solution. You dont know if RethingDB offers this feature? I was thinking of something like elasticsearch queries maybe.

Comment: No, RethinkDB doesn't offer this yet. It probably will in the upcoming months. FYI, I've been working on something called rethinkdb-proxy which does exactly this. I'll publish in the next couple of days. https://github.com/thejsj/rethinkdb-proxy

Comment: Thats really great. Thanks, this answers my question.